# get all transactions info of Cardano by using third party 'Blockfrost' with only 1 time call api?

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node, cardano-serialization-lib, cardano-api

I'm a noob about Cardano, i wonder if be able to get all transactions info of cardano by passing an specific address.
For example i have an specific address is:
addr1qy7nlfwaw3jsfftcnewgqg27dwa08uqeamjhs29tr5rgszun8netpzv3gpj5enhz36nhnw2jjfknfya64nwhgfw6ze2qhvj0xx (have 8 transactions)

- like the way in ethereum scan: has provided puclic api and just pass the specific ethereum address (normal transactions type), i will get all of transactions info (blockNumber, timeStamp, hash, address from, address to, value, gasPrice,.....) by just only one time call API.

-> but with Blockfrost as i what knew, if need to get all transactions info, it is not possible to use 1 call APIs to receice all 8 transactions, it takes many calls to get info about each transaction.
first of all, need to get all address transaction (
[https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/accounts/{stake_address}/addresses](https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/accounts/%7Bstake_address%7D/addresses) or can be use [https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/addresses/{address}/transactions](https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/addresses/%7Baddress%7D/transactions)) to get a list of transactions hash, then with each transactions hash -> will be call or need to go throught a few more APIs to get the address info)

I'v would appreciate if some one can help me for this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like neither [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io/) nor [Koios](https://koios.rest/) (another Cardano API) provide this at this point in time. In both APIs you have to query the TX hashes first and then query the details of each TX seperately.

Koios is a community driven project, so you can propose this change in one of their channels on Telegram or Discord if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Koios does seem to support multiple tx hashes now: https://api.koios.rest/#post-/tx_info